# Most efficient vector source format to load and render in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-6

I am in the process of translating netCDF and GeoTiff raster data formats into vector formats to visualize in OpenLayers. What is the most efficient Openlayers vector source format to load and render features, for example, CSV or GeoJson? Would this be the same for webGL PointsLayers? I am loading very large sets of point data using version 6.3.1.

Comment: JSON is supported directly by JavaScript so GeoJSON would be the most efficient format for a JavaScript application such as OpenLayers to parse.  How the data is loaded should have no effect on the rendering method as it must always be loaded before it can be rendered.

Comment: @Mike your comment has served me well. Would you like to submit it as an answer?